# Redirect to the page from where user clicked signin after login in django3.0

Tags: django, authentication, redirect

i want to redirect the user to the page from where he clicked the login instead of home. 
login view:

```
def login_view(request):
    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')

    if request.POST:
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm()

    context['login_form'] = form
    return render(request, "account/login.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve the the current url & redirect to it by using `HTTP_REFERER`. You can pass the url name as second parameter where you want to redirect if `HTTP_REFERER` fails.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'secondary_url_name'))
```

Comment: Means?page keeps on refreshing?

Comment: no. it's showing : This page isn’t working
localhost 
redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS